# Simple, ugly function to produce an orientation from an angle.

Tags: python

I wrote a function that takes a degree and returns the orientation as 'N', 'NE', ...etc. Very simple, but it's ugly - is there any way to rewrite this to make it...prettier?

```
def orientation(tn):
    if 23 <= tn <= 67:
        o = 'NE'
    elif 68 <= tn <= 113:
        o = 'E'    
    elif 114 <= tn <= 158:
        o = 'SE'
    elif 159 <= tn <= 203:
        o = 'S'
    elif 204 <= tn <= 248:
        o = 'SW'
    elif 249 <= tn <= 293:
        o = 'W'
    elif 294 <= tn <= 338:
        o = 'NW'
    else:
        o = 'N'
    return o
```

Comment: Unless you have some crazy overloads you're not showing, this will fail for tn = 340. Actually, this won't even run, as shown.

Comment: What if I enter 510?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [bisection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import bisect_left

directions = ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'N']
boundaries = [22,  67,   113, 158,  203, 248,  293, 338,  360]

def orientation(tn):
    return directions[bisect_left(boundaries, tn)]
```

`bisect_left()` (very efficiently) finds the index into which you'd insert `tn` into the `boundaries` list; that index is then mapped into the `directions` list to translate to a string.

Bisection only takes up to 4 steps to find the right boundary (`log2(len(boundaries))`).

You could also add 22 and divide the value modulo 360 by 45:

```
directions = ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'N']

def orientation(tn):
    index = ((tn + 22) % 360) // 45
    return directions[index]
```

However, your original boundaries were not evenly distributed at 45 degrees each, so this gives a slightly different result (your `N` boundaries span 44 degrees, while `E` is allotted 46 degrees). Bisection doesn't care about such exceptions; you can shift the boundaries all you like.

Comment: daaaamn Martijn. Back at it again with the `bisect` library.

Comment: Glad that he did, I did not know about it.

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the integer index into a list of compass directions:

```
def compass(angle):
    return ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'N'][int(8*(angle+22.)/360)]
```

Comment: While it is short, it's quite annoying to parse for a human in comparison to [Martijn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38982734/476496).

Answer (score 4):

Try to make a whole number division by 45 and address an array member by this number (index). The array should contain directions.

Answer (score 1):

Same principle, but much clearer imo, making use of the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead:

```
def orientation(tn):
  tn = mod(tn, 360)
  return "N"  if tn < 23  else \
         "NE" if tn < 68  else \
         "E"  if tn < 114 else \
         "SE" if tn < 159 else \
         "S"  if tn < 204 else \
         "SW" if tn < 249 else \
         "W"  if tn < 294 else \
         "NW" if tn < 339 else \
         "N"
```

Obviously this method doesn't generalise to other scenarios, but personally, for your particular problem I would actually prefer this over a more generalisable alternative as it is simple, clear, readable, straightforward code: anyone landing on this definition would know exactly what it does at the blink of an eye, regardless of programming skill. :p